# Proof for divergence of $\int_1^\infty \cos(x^\frac{3}{4})$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

As the title says, I am unable to find a proper proof for the divergence of

$$\int_1^\infty \cos(x^{3/4})$$

As its is not positive, I can't use any of the divergence tests, nor compare it to a sum.

Opening the integral and trying to solve it is resulting in something very ugly, and I doubt that it is the right way to do it.

Could use some help, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the graph of $\cos(x^{3/4})$? Should be pretty clear why it diverges.

Comment: i know it diverges, i am looking for a proper formal proof

Comment: @DavidZhang Actually it's not really entirely clear. $\int_1^{\infty} \ \cos(x^2) \ dx$ converges.

Comment: @Zach466920 Whilst $\int_1^{\infty}\cos x^2\,dx$ converges, the integral of interest does not.  Just substitute $x=t^{4/3}$.

Comment: @Zach466920 The difference is that with $\cos(x^2)$, the positive and negative lobes of the graph get narrower and narrower. With $\cos(x^{3/4})$ they only get wider, so the integral can never settle down to any value.

Comment: @DavidZhang Why do you think that I was under the impression it converged? I was just saying it wasn't "obvious". However if you cheat and go to the complex plane, it's clearer that $e^{i \cdot x}$ doesn't converge and thus the Fresnel integral doesn't converge.

Comment: @Zach466920 I'm not trying to imply that you believe the integral converges. I'm just trying to explain why it's "obvious" (at least in my opinion) that $\int \cos(x^{3/4})$ fails to converge.

Comment: It might be interesting to see what happens if we give the divergent integral a meaning using analytic continuation. Mathematica gives $f(p) = \int_1^\infty \cos(x^p) \,dx = \frac{1}{p}\left(\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{2 p}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)-p\left( \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1}{2 p};\frac{1}{2},1+\frac{1}{2 p};-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)\right)$. Where $F$ is a hypergeometric function. At $p\to\frac{1}{3}$ we have $f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{2 \pi } \left(J_{\frac{5}{2}}(1)-J_{\frac{3}{2}}(1)\right) \simeq -0.717401$ where $J$ is the Bessel function.

Comment: Since x^{3/4} increases more slowly than x, the area of each segment of cos 'wave' goes larger as $x\to\infty$, instead of getting to 0, so the integral diverges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**

Enforce the substitution $x=t^{4/3}$.  Then, $dx=\frac43 t^{1/3}\,dt$. Therefore, we have

$$\int_1^\infty \cos(x^{3/4})\,dx=\frac43\int_1^\infty t^{1/3}\cos (t)\,dt$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: And now open the improper integral and solve for the lim? That's results in some thing very ugly, i was hoping there is a more gracefully way to prove this

Comment: @OrDinari You need not evaluate the integral at a finite upper limit to establish that this improper integral diverges.

Comment: How do i establish that the improper integral diverges then (when none of the divergence tests apply as it is not positive)? i am sorry, i feel like i am missing some thing.

Comment: @OrDinari: Working with the integrand on the right hand side, on intervals of the form $[2n\pi - \pi/2, 2n\pi + \pi/2]$ the cosine is positive, and the area will be approximately (treating $t^{1/3}$ as a constant on the interval) $(2n\pi)^{1/3} A$, where $A = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos(t) dt$. Similarly, on intervals of the form $[2n\pi + \pi/2, 2n\pi + 3\pi/2]$, the area will be approximately $-(2n\pi)^{1/3} A$. So, integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ is approximately the same as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n n^{1/3}$ times a constant. Clearly this series diverges (terms don't converge to 0).

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: You can do this and integrate by parts twice as well. One of the boundary terms will clearly diverge while the other boundary term and the left over integral will converge.

Comment: @nayrb I believe that your comment should really be expanded into another answer. It's a very interesting method of showing integral divergence.

Comment: Too lazy, but if you want to @yo' go ahead!

Comment: I suggest a simple application of the  Cauchy Criterion for improper Riemann integrals.  One can easily show the negation in a way analogous to that suggested by @Bungo.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very long approach.

$$(1) \quad e^{ix^p}=\cos(x^p)+\sin(x^p) \cdot i$$

So we can learn a lot from the integral,

$$(2) \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx$$

Let's set up a contour integral that goes from $[0,\infty)$; then moves over a circle arc from $R$ to some $\theta \cdot R$ then comes back to the origin. In mathematical form have,

$$(3) \quad \int_C e^{-z^{p}} \ dz=\int_{0}^{R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx+\color{red}{\int_{C_R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx}-\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{R \cdot \theta} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx}$$

We'd like to pick $\theta$ so that the red integral goes away and the blue one is equivalent to an integral over $(1)$. If substitute $x=u \cdot \theta$ into the blue integral, we get,

$$(4) \quad \int_C e^{-z^{p}} \ dz=\int_{0}^{R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx+\color{red}{\int_{C_R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx}-\theta \cdot \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{R} e^{-\theta^{p} \cdot x^{p}} \ dx}$$

So we need $-\theta^{p}=i$. One solution is $\theta=e^{-\cfrac{\pi}{2p} \cdot i}$. This makes the red integral zero as long as $p \gt 1$. If $p \lt 1$ then the red integral doesn't go to zero, and thus the contour integral doesn't converge, and as well see, the real integral is finite. This would imply that the integral in question diverges. Since there are no singularities enclosed by the contour, the integral is $0$. So we have,

$$0=\int_{0}^{R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx-\theta \cdot \color{blue}{\int_{0}^{R} e^{i \cdot x^{p}} \ dx}$$

Which implies that,

$$\int_{0}^{R} e^{i \cdot x^{p}} \ dx=\cfrac{1}{\theta} \cdot \int_{0}^{R} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx$$

If we take the real part of this, and take the limit as $R$ approaches infinity, we have the relation,

$$\int_0^{\infty} \cos(x^p) \ dx=\operatorname{Re}\left(\cfrac{1}{\theta} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx \right)$$

Recall that,

$$(5) \quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^{p}} \ dx=\cfrac{\Gamma\left(\cfrac{1}{p}\right)}{p}$$

So we have,

$$(6) \quad \int_0^{\infty} \cos(x^p) \ dx=\cfrac{1}{p} \cdot \Gamma\left(\cfrac{1}{p}\right) \cdot \cos\left(\cfrac{\pi}{2p}\right) \ , \quad p \gt 1$$

Since $\cos(x^p)$ has a finite range on $[0,1]$ the results that follow hold equally for your integral.

$$\int_1^{\infty} \cos(x^{3/4}) \ dx$$

diverges because $p=3/4 \lt 1$.

Comment: Great solution! By the way, how do you prove $(5)$ is true?

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f(x)=\cos x^{3/4}$.

Let $a_k = (2k\pi+\pi/2)^{4/3}$ and $b_k = (2k\pi+3\pi/2)^{4/3}$.
These are the zeros of the integrand, and are order in the following way: $a_0 < b_0 < a_1 < b_1 < \dotsb$. What can we say about

$$A_{k} := \int_{a_{k}}^{b_{k}} f(x)dx \text{ and } B_{k} := \int_{b_{k}}^{a_{k+1}} f(x) dx$$

Hint: $A_k>0$ is an increasing sequence and $B_k<0$ is decreasing, and

$$ \int_1^\infty f(x) dx = \int_1^{a_0} f(x) dx + A_0 + B_0 + A_1 + B_1 + \dotsm$$

(has to be taken properly, this holds if the integral was convergent; since the sum on the right is divergent, the integral is divergent as well.)